# Create column in list with link to open document in document library

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-addin, custom-list

I have created a custom list in SharePoint 2013 (Office 365) using the Import Spreadsheet App. This has provided me with the columns (Project Code, Title, Author, Medium, Quarter, hyperlink, etc.) and data I need to search by, however, now I need to create a new column which will link to the relevant document in my document library. I have tried using a lookup field but this only provides me with folder names and opens the folder location not the document itself.

I realize I can add columns within the document library however I have thousands of records already entered in my spreadsheet which is why I went the Import Spreadsheet App route.

Should I be looking at different document library structures (i.e. document sets) or is this something that can be solved using a workflow? I have read several forums and can't seem to find a solution to this.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your existing **hyperlink** field is the the URL to your document you can indeed add a Calculated Column.

You have to set it to datatype=Number otherwise the Column will just display your HTML code as Text

```
="<a href='" & Title & "' target='_blank'> " & hyperlink & "</a>"
```

Note: your hyperlink fields must be a Single Line Of Text, as a Calculated Formula can not access a HyperLink/Picture field.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the URL of the document, you can use a calculated column to combine a url and the item name.

The formula would be:

```
="<a href='"&%URL_Field_Name%&"'> "&[%field_name%]&"</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by field formatting to generate a link.

See also
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#turn-field-values-into-hyperlinks-basic

This is a working example from this Microsoft page:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + @currentField"
   }
}
```

The two mentioned solutions are not possible anymore. Microsoft says: "will block the execution of custom markup in calculated fields in SharePoint Online from June 13, 2017 onwards"

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields-a3db28e4-747c-437e-b085-8f795b722a8c