# Opening Links List in New Window

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation

We are using on-premise Sharepoint 2013..I'm more a power user and I'm used to SP Designer 2010 that actually had something for the Power User..Like Actual Design...I am looking for a way to open links from a links list in a new window using the js link from the web part tools..

I've been able to "open in a new window"  by manipulating the "Target" attribute in designer, I think I was using a DataView to do this  (I really don't want to make a dataview web part, because I want to stay away from being controller for all things SharePoint @ my job and make it more possible for others to do something without my help.)

I know this is old hat for all of you...But I am so unfamiliar with using the js link...

Thanks to All...

Comment: I know it was answered here.....But I think I am missing something, putting it in a file and referencing that file in the js link webpart field didn't seem to work...I think I'm missing it. 

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116482/spo-2013-how-to-open-links-list-items-websites-in-a-new-window-tab-when-clic

Comment: The answer there relies on jQuery being loaded.  Do you know if jQuery is getting loaded on the page that is showing your links list?

Comment: For alternative using Calculated Column see: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144885/create-column-in-list-with-link-to-open-document-in-document-library

Answer (score 1):

To resume you want a List of Links that lets you open the links in new Window (Or Tab) ?
Try to create a list using **Promoted Links Template**. It offers a column **Launch Behavior**. After creating the list edit the default value of that column to **New Tab**. And without any js you have achieved you goal.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using jQuery by inserting the below code in a content editor web part above the links list.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".ms-vb a").attr('target', '_blank');     
     });
</script>
```

​

Comment: This works is summary view! But my list is grouped and as soon as I group the list, it stops working..